# Creating a directory hash with filename

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a file path:

```
a = "./users/mark/bobapples/Folder/SubFolder/File.txt"
```

and a hash

```
h = {}
```

What is the most efficient way to map all directories in the hash, something like:

```
a.split("/")
=> [".", "users", "mark", "bobapples", "Folder", "SubFolder", "File.txt"]
h["."] = {} if !h["."]
h["."]["users"] = {} if !h["."]["users"]
h["."]["users"]["mark"] = {} if !h["."]["users"]["mark"]
```

and so on.

Comment: Not understanding your need.. Feeling so dumb :p

Comment: I want to create a hash that contains all the directories as keys. So if `a = "./foo/bar.txt"` , `h = {"."=>{"foo"=>{}}}` another eg, `b = "./hello/world.txt"`, `h = {"."=>{"foo"=>{},"hello"=>{}}}`. Sorry I think I did not do a good job explaining my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand....

Is it this:

```
hash=current={};a.split('/')[0..-2].each{|dir| current[dir]={};current=current[dir]}

hash
=> {"."=>{"users"=>{"mark"=>{"bobapples"=>{"Folder"=>{"SubFolder"=>{}}}}}}}
```

Or shorter using inject:

```
a.split('/')[0..-2].inject(hash={}){|current,dir| current[dir]={}}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted to do, I am validating it with a few more sample data. So far, so good. +1

Comment: Late to the party. Looks about great! :)

Comment: thanks @tomsoft, this works great. Can you please explain how `hash=current={}` works? That will be very helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: in fact hash=current={} is equivalent to:

    current={} followed by
    hash=current

Comment: but try to use the "inject" version which is smarter.... Also the [0..-2] is to remove the latest entry (Files.txt) which seems that that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

### Reverse the array and create the result hash from inside out:

```
h={}
a.split("/").reverse.each{|e| h = {e => h.dup}}
h
#=>{"."=>{"users"=>{"mark"=>{"bobapples"=>{"Folder"=>{"SubFolder"=>{"File.txt"=>{}}}}}}}}
```

### Inject version with file name as the value of the deepest directory :

```
h = a.split('/').reverse[1..-1].inject(a.split("/").last) {|memo, o| {o => memo} }
#=> {"."=>{"users"=>{"mark"=>{"bobapples"=>{"Folder"=>{"SubFolder"=>"File.txt"}}}}}}
```

*Thanks for @lokson's help by the way!*

Comment: `a.split('/').reverse.reduce {|memo, o| {o => memo} }`

Comment: @lokson Very nice trick, If you post on your answer, I'll delete mine.

Comment: @shivam the last version may what you really want. Wish it helps.